# Problem regarding partial differentiation and integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I have a question and I solved it. but, I am quite not sure whether my method is correct or not:

Problem:

> Let $f_1,f_2:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable and suppose $D_1f_2=D_2f_1$.
> Let $F(x,y)=\int_0^xf_1(t,0)\ dt\ +\ \int_0^yf_2(x,t)\ dt$.
> Show that $D_1F(x,y)=f_1(x,y)$.

My Solution:

\begin{align} D_1F(x,y)&=D_1\int_0^xf_1(t,0)\ dt\ +\ D_1\int_0^yf_2(x,t)\ dt.\\ 
&=f_1(x,0) \ +\ \int_0^yD_1f_2(x,t)\ dt\\
&=f_1(x,0) \ +\ \int_0^yD_2f_1(x,t)\ dt\\
&=f_1(x,0) \ +\ f_1(x,y)-f_1(x,0)\ dt\\
&=f_1(x,y)
\end{align}

I am not sure about my solution and didn't use the continuously differentiable property anywhere. I feel my solution is not rigorous enough. Any advice is highly valuable. Thank you

Comment: Why is $D_1\int_0^yf_2(x,t)\,dt=\int_0^yD_1f_2(x,t)\,dt$? Also, why is $\int_0^yD_2f_1(x,t)\,dt=f_1(x,y)-f_1(x,0)$? (note you have a small typo you wrote $f(x,0)$)

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you for pointing out the mistake. I got your point